# How to solve this deprecation issue "abs is deprecated: Please use the `abs(_)` free function"

Tags: swift, core-graphics, deprecated

I have a Swift file where I import Foundation and CoreGraphics, but at the place where I call `abs(x)` where `x` is a `CGFloat`, I get this warning:

> abs is deprecated: Please use the `abs(_)` free function

What function should I use?

Thank you

Comment: Where exactly are you calling `abs(x)`? Please provide a [mcve]. Sounds like you're calling `CGFloat`'s static `abs` method rather than the top-level `abs` function. Are you calling it at static scope in a `CGFloat` extension by any chance?

Comment: It's giving no warning in xcode 8.2
let a: Double = 10.03  let value =  abs(a)

Comment: what version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: @Hamish have a look at the api changes https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/double/1538930-abs?changes=latest_minor . i guess this is a bug in xcode 8.0-8.1

Comment: @Hamish Yup that's excactly what I am doing, calling it in a static function extending CGFloat !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That seems to be [a compiler bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4170), if you are using `abs(x)` in a `static` context.

According to the comments you can work around the warning by using:

```
Swift.abs(x)
```

Comment: I wouldn't *really* consider it a bug – I would expect a call to `abs(_:)` in a static context on a type that has a static method `abs(_:)` to by default resolve to *that* method, rather than the top-level `abs(_:)`. But yes, using `Swift.` is the proper way to disambiguate in this case :)

Comment: @Hamish Agree. I thought about writing more but was not really sure how this case is supposed to be handled. It's filed as an open bug though.